# Executing external commands in parallel and capturing the output in an array in Rust

Tags: rust, rayon

I have the following while loop that runs `generate_user_key` for each of the file in the `file_array`, and outputs the result. I would like to parallelize this such that an array of the generated keys is returned, and the process is **executed in parallel** instead of sequential to make it faster.

```
use std::process::Command;

//file_array definition here

let mut i = 0;
while (i<100) {
  let generated_key = Command::new("generate_user_key")
                       .arg(file_array[i])
                       .output()
                       .expect("generate_user_key command failed to start");
  println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&generated_key.stdout));
  i=i+1;
}
```

What is the best way to implement this in rust?

Comment: what is `file_array` type in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop over the array items using [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/) then you can simply create [`into_par_iter`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#tymethod.into_par_iter) and work on array items

```rs
use std::process::Command;
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let result: Vec<_> = arr.into_par_iter().flat_map(|value| {
        let output = Command::new("sh")
                .args(["-c", &format!("echo {}", value)])
                .output()
                .expect("failed to execute process");
        println!("Index: {}, Output: {:?}", value, output.stdout);
        output.stdout
    });

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

You can also use `range` to loop over and use the `counter` as `array` index

```rs
use std::process::Command;
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let result: Vec<_> = (0..arr.len()).into_par_iter().flat_map(|idx| {
        let output = Command::new("sh")
                .args(["-c", &format!("echo {}", arr[idx])])
                .output()
                .expect("failed to execute process");
        println!("Index: {}, Output: {:?}", idx, output.stdout);
        output.stdout
    });

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

#### Example using [`thread`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-01-threads.html)

```rs
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];
    for idx in 0..arr.len() {
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || -> Vec<_> {
            let output = Command::new("sh")
                    .args(["-c", &format!("echo -n {}", idx)])
                    .output()
                    .expect("failed to execute process");
            println!("Index: {}, Output: {:?}", idx, output.stdout);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
            output.stdout
        }));
    }

    let result = threads.into_iter().flat_map(|c| c.join().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan. In the case of into_par_iter, if I need to add the output to an array instead of printing it, how would I do that? Thanks

Comment: @SaqibAli you can use [`map`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.map) or [`flat_map`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.flat_map) to collect the result as `vec` or `array`

Comment: When I run the first one, I get "the trait `ParallelIterator` is not implemented for `&str`"

Comment: @SaqibAli please can you share how you are trying the first example in your question

Comment: @SaqibAli it seems you are trying to use the example in data of [`&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) type which does not implement [`iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#) trait, for string you can check [here](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/str/trait.ParallelString.html).

Comment: I have an Vector string that I am iterating over.

Comment: @SaqibAli please attach the sample code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to do with [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon). E.g. something like this (untested since I don't have your `generate_user_key`):

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
let keys = (0..100).into_par_iter().map (|_| {
        Command::new("generate_user_key")
            .arg(file_array[i])
            .output()
            .expect("generate_user_key command failed to start")
            .stdout
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

or better:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
let keys = file_array.par_iter().map (|f| {
        Command::new("generate_user_key")
            .arg(f)
            .output()
            .expect("generate_user_key command failed to start")
            .stdout
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

When all else fails, throw threads at the problem. It almost certainly isn't the correct approach, but it works.

```rust
let mut join_handles = Vec::new();

for _ in 0..100 {
    join_handles.push(thread::spawn(|| {
        let generated_key = Command::new("generate_user_key")
                              .arg(file_array[i])
                              .output()
                              .expect("generate_user_key command failed to start");

        String::from_utf8_lossy(&generated_key.stdout)
    }));
}

let outputs = join_handles.into_iter().map(Result::unwrap).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

**Edit:** The correct solution is probably using `Command::spawn` to start the processes without blocking. The OS can then handle running them in parallel and you can then collect the outputs.

Comment: Maybe you should add code on how to use `Command::spawn` instead of how to start threads, since you say the former is the correct solution, which the latter is the plan B.

Comment: Where is the i for file_array[i] getting set?